# How do I slow down file transfer between drives?

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer, speed, window

I recently got a 2tb drive and I made the mistake of assuming the drive was working fine and moving a lot of my files onto it. I tried to move some of the files back to my original drive, but I noticed when the file transfer speed stays around 200 mb/s for too long, the drive starts making weird noises before unmounting and remounting itself and stopping the transfer. I think I got a bad drive, but if this sounds like a different issue, like power draw, let me know. When I was transferring different files, which transferred at a slower speed of around 16 mb/s, it was able to transfer them without any problems. I want to slow the transfer speed between these drives so that way I am able to recover all of my files back onto my main drive. Is there any program or windows setting that lets me do this? Everywhere I looked was either people complaining about slow transfer speeds or a guide showing how to increase your transfer speed, but I wasn't able to find anything about deliberately slowing the transfer speed. This is really important to me because if I don't find a way to slow down the speed, I won't be able to ever recover any of my larger files

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems as a typical X-Y question. Slowing down the copy does not avoid disk read errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is no windows setting for this. You'll have to use programs to accomplish this.

In your case, choosing Free File Sync is your best option. The free version has only 2 files asynchronous transfer, which is not too fast. Should aid well in what you want to achieve. The donation option allows you to change this, so you can set it to 1. Which would be more optimal.

Your transfer speed is so high because by default it will transfer many files at the same time.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, I downloaded FreeFileSync and I think I figured out how to use it to copy files, but I don't see any options to limit speed. Where are they?

Comment: Nevermind, I found a workaround where I used 7zip to zip all of my files into 300 megabyte packages, and its able to transfer the full 300mb without crashing so I'm just moving each file over, waiting a few seconds, and then moving the next